# .htaccess keep multiple GET params

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Part 1 takes care of making `example.com/fr` behave like `example.com?lang=fr`, or `example.com/fr/some-page.php` like `example.com/some.page.php?lang=fr` etc.

Part 2, which I'm currently working on not working well yet, is to obtain a new GET param for other pages called `page`, in this case if there's `login` in the url.

Problem: It seems like part of the page loads twice when going to for example `example.com/login` or `example.com/fr/login`.

Maybe un-necessary details here but for instance it says `Facebook Pixel Error: Duplicate Pixel ID:`, and similar errors for other tags I use like Mixpanel, and then my JS just stops working. That's all I can say about the problems I see on my side. Best chance seems to be about looking for flagrant errors in the htaccess rules.

What should be fixed in the rules so the end goal of having the GET param `page` and `lang` work fine?

```
RewriteEngine On

# Part 1
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+[^?]*\?lang=([^\s&]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%2/%1? [R=301,L,NE]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/js/
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})(?:/([^/]+))?$ $2?lang=$1 [NC,L,QSA]


# Part 2 (this is the part I am adding, which isn't fully working well yet)
# anything looking flagrantly wrong? If for example we are on `example.com/fr/login`,
# according to rules in this htaccess file we should have 2 GET params, `lang` and `page`.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} login
RewriteRule .* index.php?page=login

# adding more pages the same way
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} signup
RewriteRule .* index.php?page=signup
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following rule as your Part1

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(en|fr)/login/?$ /index.php?page=login [L]


RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?lang=([^&]+)\sHTTP
RewriteRule ^ /%1%{REQUEST_URI}? [L,R]
RewriteRule ^(en|fr)/?(.*\.php)?$ /$2?lang=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Hi, the issue is still there, and it created a new problem -- a page such as `example.com/fr/some-page.php` is not working. `example.com/fr` (`example.com/XX`) still work.

Comment: Ok for some reason the rule works now after re-testing. It doesn't fix the initial problem, but it simplifies the htaccess file by removing one line.

Comment: @DanP could you please be more specific about the issue you are having?

Comment: It's hard to explain besides saying that the only thing that happens is that Facebook says (error in console) `Facebook Pixel Error: Duplicate Pixel ID:` however without the rules in PART 2, everything is fine. There's nothing about the rules in part 2 that are flagrantly wrong, and could be conflicting with other rules? For example `example.com/fr/login`, according to rules, gives 2 GET params (`lang` and `page`) fine?

Comment: And following that Facebook error, my page's JS doesn't work.

Comment: Hi starkeen -- any idea if Part 2 is looking fine?

Comment: @danP Your rule is fine, Actually /login uri is being handled by the first rule and that is why you are getting 2get perms. You need to reorder your rules. Try the updated rule

Comment: Also, I DO need 2 GET params IF you visit a page such as /fr/login. The 2 GET params, as we can see in rules, should be `lang` (fr) and `page` (login)

Comment: Without any language param, the page for example `example.com/login` doesn't work

Comment: Working -- simply change `RewriteRule ^(en|fr)/login/?$ /index.php?page=login [L]` to  `RewriteRule login/?$ /index.php?page=login [L]`